# Swift 4 How to return a smaller array from array of dictionaries

Tags: swift4

I'm trying to sort and then cut 20 quiz questions from an array containing 50. The quiz questions are dictionaries.

```
    var quizQuestionsRaw = [[String:String]]()
    var quizQuestions = [[String:String]]()
    quizQuestionsRaw = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: quizQuestionsRaw) as! [[String:String]]
```

Then I tried

```
quizQuestions = quizQuestionsRaw.removeFirst(30) as! [[String:String]]
```

But I just got an error. Can someone help with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Try this..

```
//First We'll Create an Extension to Shuffle Array
extension Array
{
    mutating func shuffle()
    {
          for _ in 0..<10
        {
              sort { (_,_) in arc4random() < arc4random() }
     }
  }
}

 // Replace this Array of Dictionary With your Q&A Array
 var array:[[String: String]] = [["Q1":"A1"],["Q2":"A2"],["Q3":"A3"],["Q4":"A4"],["Q5":"A5"]....["Q30":"A30"]]
 array.shuffle()

  // This line will return last 20 elements of array
 array.suffix(20)
```

If you're using Swift 4.2 or later version you don't need to create an extension to shuffle array in that case, this line is sufficient

```
array.shuffled()
```

Good Luck :)